# 'case item is unreachable' in Vivado synthesis process

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx, hdl, vivado

```
`timescale  1ns/1ps

module lcd_control (
    input clk,
    input reset,
    input prod1,
    input prod2,
    input prod3,
    input prod4,
    input disp_up,
    input disp_down,
    input confirm,
    input cancel,   
    output lcd_e,
    output reg lcd_rs,
    output reg lcd_rw,
    output reg [7:0] lcd_data
);

reg [3:0] state;
reg [3:0] n_state;
parameter delay = 4'b0000;
parameter funtion_set = 4'b0001;
parameter entry_mode = 4'b0010;
parameter disp_onoff = 4'b0011;
parameter line1_list = 4'b0100;
parameter line2_list = 4'b0101;
parameter delay_t = 4'b0110;
parameter select = 4'b0111;
parameter up_disp = 4'b1000;
parameter down_disp = 4'b1001;
parameter cola = 4'b1010;
parameter water = 4'b1011;
parameter coffee = 4'b1100;
parameter tea = 4'b1101;
parameter clear_disp = 4'b1110;


integer cnt;
integer cnt_100hz;
reg clk_100hz;

wire disp_down_100, disp_up_100, prod1_100, prod2_100, prod3_100, prod4_100, confirm_100, cancel_100;

always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
    if(reset) begin
        cnt_100hz <= 0;
        clk_100hz <= 0;
    end
    else if(cnt_100hz >= 4) begin
        cnt_100hz <= 0;
        clk_100hz <= ~clk_100hz;
    end
    else
    cnt_100hz <= cnt_100hz + 1;
end


always @(posedge clk_100hz or posedge reset) begin //state control
    if(reset)
    state <= delay;
    else begin
        case (state)
        delay:          if(cnt == 70) state <= funtion_set; 
        funtion_set:    if(cnt == 30) state <= disp_onoff; 
        disp_onoff:     if(cnt == 30) state <= entry_mode;
        entry_mode:     if(cnt == 30) state <= line1_list; 
        line1_list:     if(cnt == 40) state <= line2_list; 
        line2_list:     if(cnt == 40) state <= delay_t;
        delay_t:        if(cnt == 10) state <= select;
        select:         case ({disp_up_100, disp_down_100, prod1_100, prod2_100, prod3_100, prod4_100})
                        6'b100000: state <= up_disp; 
                        6'b010000: state <= down_disp; 
                        6'b001000: begin n_state <= cola;       state <= clear_disp; end
                        6'b000100: begin n_state <= water;      state <= clear_disp; end
                        6'b000010: begin n_state <= tea;        state <= clear_disp; end
                        6'b000001: begin n_state <= coffee;     state <= clear_disp; end
                        default: state <= select;
                        endcase 
        up_disp:        if(cnt == 39) state <= select;
        down_disp:      if(cnt == 39) state <= select;
        clear_disp:     if(cnt == 40) state <= n_state;
        cola:           if(confirm_100 | cancel_100) state <= delay_t;
        water:          if(confirm_100 | cancel_100) state <= delay_t;
        tea:            if(confirm_100 | cancel_100) state <= delay_t;
        coffee:         if(confirm_100 | cancel_100) state <= delay_t;
        delay_t:        if(cnt == 10) state <= line1_list;
        default:        state = delay;
        endcase
    end
end

always @(posedge clk_100hz or posedge reset) begin //cnt control
    if(reset)
    cnt <= 0;
    else begin
        case (state)
        delay:          begin if(cnt == 70) cnt<=0; else cnt<=cnt+1; end
        funtion_set:    begin if(cnt == 30) cnt<=0; else cnt<=cnt+1; end
        disp_onoff:     begin if(cnt == 30) cnt<=0; else cnt<=cnt+1; end
        entry_mode:     begin if(cnt == 30) cnt<=0; else cnt<=cnt+1; end
        line1_list:     begin if(cnt == 40) cnt<=0; else cnt<=cnt+1; end
        line2_list:     begin if(cnt == 40) cnt<=0; else cnt<=cnt+1; end
        delay_t:        begin if(cnt == 10) cnt<=0; else cnt<=cnt+1; end
        up_disp:        begin if(cnt == 39) cnt<=0; else cnt<=cnt+1; end
        down_disp:      begin if(cnt == 39) cnt<=0; else cnt<=cnt+1; end
        cola:           begin if(cnt == 40) begin
                        if(confirm_100 | cancel_100) cnt<=0; 
                        else cnt<=cnt; end
                        else cnt<=cnt+1; end
        water:          begin if(cnt == 40) begin
                        if(confirm_100 | cancel_100) cnt<=0; 
                        else cnt<=cnt; end
                        else cnt<=cnt+1; end
        tea:            begin if(cnt == 40) begin
                        if(confirm_100 | cancel_100) cnt<=0; 
                        else cnt<=cnt; end
                        else cnt<=cnt+1; end
        coffee:         begin if(cnt == 40) begin
                        if(confirm_100 | cancel_100) cnt<=0; 
                        else cnt<=cnt; end
                        else cnt<=cnt+1; end
        clear_disp:     begin if(cnt == 40) cnt <=0; else cnt<=cnt+1; end
        delay_t:        begin if(cnt == 10) cnt <=0; else cnt<=cnt+1; end
        default: cnt<=0;
        endcase
    end
end

always @(posedge clk_100hz or posedge reset) begin
    if(reset) begin
        lcd_rs<=1;
        lcd_rw<=1;
        lcd_data<=8'b00000000;
    end
    else begin
        case (state)
        funtion_set: begin
            lcd_rs<=0;
            lcd_rw<=0;
            lcd_data<=8'b00111000;
        end
        disp_onoff: begin
            lcd_rs<=0;
            lcd_rw<=0;
            lcd_data<=8'b00001100;
        end
        entry_mode: begin
            lcd_rs<=0;
            lcd_rw<=0;
            lcd_data<=8'b00000110;
        end
        line1_list: begin //line1 control
            lcd_rw<=0;
            case (cnt)
            0: begin    lcd_rs<=0;  lcd_data<=8'b10000000;  end
            1: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h31;        end
            2: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h2E;        end
            3: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h43;        end
            4: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h4F;        end
            5: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h4C;        end
            6: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h41;        end                         
            7: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h20;        end                                         
            8: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h20;        end                                         
            9: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h20;        end                             
            10: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h20;        end                                         
            11: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h31;        end                                         
            12: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h36;        end                                         
            13: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h30;        end                                         
            14: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h30;        end                         
            15: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h57;        end                                         
            16: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h1E;        end                                     
            17: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h33;        end                                         
            18: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h2E;        end                                 
            19: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h43;        end                                     
            20: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h4F;        end                                         
            21: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h46;        end                                         
            22: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h46;        end                             
            23: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h45;        end                                         
            24: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h45;        end                         
            25: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h20;        end                                         
            26: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h20;        end                                         
            27: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h31;        end                                         
            28: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h30;        end                                         
            29: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h30;        end                                         
            30: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h30;        end                                         
            31: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h57;        end                 
            32: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h1E;        end                             
            default: begin  lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h20;    end
            endcase
        end
        line2_list:begin //line2 control
            lcd_rw<=0;
            case (cnt)
            0: begin    lcd_rs<=0;  lcd_data<=8'b11000000;  end                                             
            1: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h32;        end                             
            2: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h2E;        end                                         
            3: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h57;        end                             
            4: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h41;        end                                         
            5: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h54;        end                                         
            6: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h45;        end                                         
            7: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h52;        end                                         
            8: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h20;        end                                 
            9: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h20;        end                                         
            10: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h20;        end                                         
            11: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h20;        end                                         
            12: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h37;        end                                         
            13: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h30;        end                                     
            14: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h30;        end                                         
            15: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h57;        end                                         
            16: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h1F;        end                                     
            17: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h34;        end                                         
            18: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h2E;        end                                         
            19: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h54;        end                         
            20: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h45;        end                                         
            21: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h41;        end                                         
            22: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h20;        end                                         
            23: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h20;        end                                         
            24: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h20;        end                                         
            25: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h20;        end                                         
            26: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h20;        end                         
            27: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h20;        end                                         
            28: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h39;        end                         
            29: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h30;        end                                         
            30: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h30;        end                         
            31: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h57;        end                                         
            32: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h1F;        end                         
            default:begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h20;    end         
            endcase
        end
        delay_t:begin
            lcd_rs<=0;
            lcd_rw<=0;
            lcd_data<=8'b00000010;
        end
        select: begin 
            lcd_rs<=0; 
            lcd_rw<=0; 
            lcd_data<=8'b00001100; 
            end
        up_disp: begin
            lcd_rs<=1;
            lcd_rw<=1;
            lcd_data<=8'b00011000; 
            end
        down_disp: begin
            lcd_rs<=1;
            lcd_rw<=1;
            lcd_data<=8'b00011100; 
            end
        clear_disp: begin
            lcd_rs<=1;
            lcd_rw<=1;
            lcd_data<=8'b00000001; 
            end
        cola: begin
            lcd_rw<=0;
            case (cnt)
            0: begin    lcd_rs<=0;  lcd_data<=8'b10000000;  end                                             
            1: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h53;        end                             
            2: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h54;        end                                         
            3: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h4F;        end                             
            4: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h43;        end                                         
            5: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h4B;        end                                         
            6: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h3A;        end                                         
            7: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h30;        end                                         
            8: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h30;        end                                                                     
            13: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h59;        end                                     
            14: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h2F;        end                                         
            15: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h4E;        end                 
            default:begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h20;    end         
            endcase
        end
        water: begin
            lcd_rw<=0;
            case (cnt)
            0: begin    lcd_rs<=0;  lcd_data<=8'b10000000;  end                                             
            1: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h53;        end                             
            2: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h54;        end                                         
            3: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h4F;        end                             
            4: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h43;        end                                         
            5: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h4B;        end                                         
            6: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h3A;        end                                         
            7: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h30;        end                                         
            8: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h30;        end                                                                     
            13: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h59;        end                                     
            14: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h2F;        end                                         
            15: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h4E;        end                 
            default:begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h20;    end         
            endcase
        end
        tea: begin
            lcd_rw<=0;
            case (cnt)
            0: begin    lcd_rs<=0;  lcd_data<=8'b10000000;  end                                             
            1: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h53;        end                             
            2: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h54;        end                                         
            3: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h4F;        end                             
            4: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h43;        end                                         
            5: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h4B;        end                                         
            6: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h3A;        end                                         
            7: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h30;        end                                         
            8: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h30;        end                                                                     
            13: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h59;        end                                     
            14: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h2F;        end                                         
            15: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h4E;        end                 
            default:begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h20;    end         
            endcase
        end
        coffee: begin
            lcd_rw<=0;
            case (cnt)
            0: begin    lcd_rs<=0;  lcd_data<=8'b10000000;  end                                             
            1: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h53;        end                             
            2: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h54;        end                                         
            3: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h4F;        end                             
            4: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h43;        end                                         
            5: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h4B;        end                                         
            6: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h3A;        end                                         
            7: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h30;        end                                         
            8: begin    lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h30;        end                                                                     
            13: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h59;        end                                     
            14: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h2F;        end                                         
            15: begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h4E;        end                 
            default:begin   lcd_rs<=1;  lcd_data<=8'h20;    end         
            endcase
        end
        delay_t: begin
            lcd_rs<=0;
            lcd_rw<=0;
            lcd_data<=8'b00000010;
        end
        default:begin
            lcd_rs<=1;
            lcd_rw<=1;
            lcd_data<=8'b00000000;
        end
        endcase
    end
end

assign lcd_e = clk_100hz;

oneshot lcd1(
    .clk(clk_100hz),
    .btn(disp_up),
    .oneshot(disp_up_100)
);

oneshot lcd2(
    .clk(clk_100hz),
    .btn(disp_down),
    .oneshot(disp_down_100)
);

oneshot lcd3(
    .clk(clk_100hz),
    .btn(prod1),
    .oneshot(prod1_100)
);

oneshot lcd4(
    .clk(clk_100hz),
    .btn(prod2),
    .oneshot(prod2_100)
);

oneshot lcd5(
    .clk(clk_100hz),
    .btn(prod3),
    .oneshot(prod3_100)
);

oneshot lcd6(
    .clk(clk_100hz),
    .btn(prod4),
    .oneshot(prod4_100)
);

oneshot lcd7(
    .clk(clk_100hz),
    .btn(confirm),
    .oneshot(confirm_100)
);

oneshot lcd8(
    .clk(clk_100hz),
    .btn(cancel),
    .oneshot(cancel_100)
);

endmodule
```

This module is a sub-module of the vending machine module, responsible for controlling the LCD.
I think I write all pass to each cases, but after synthesis, I got this error message:

> [Synth 8-151] case item 4'b0110 is unreachable

I don't know why this message appeared.

I've checked and written all the paths leading to the `delay_t` state with the 4'b0110 condition, but the error message persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicate case items in the `case` statement with `delay_t`:

```
    case (state)
    ...
    delay_t:        if(cnt == 10) state <= select;
    ...
    delay_t:        if(cnt == 10) state <= line1_list;
```

The first is reachable; the second is not.  Once `state` matches the first `delay_t` line, the `case` statement exits; it no longer looks at other case items.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 12.5 *Case statement*

Since the second case item is not used, you should either delete it or re-design your logic.